# Quick way to conditionally assign values based on a column with a lot of values?

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

Let's say my data looks like this:

```
df
ID  Location  
 1   54
 2   35 
 3   54
 4   35
 5   71
```

I'm interested in finding the frequency of visits to a given location, and then assigning that frequency (i.e. sum) to a new column based on the value in the Location column.

To begin, I've tried using the `table` function:

```
count<-as.data.frame(table(df))
count
var1  freq
54    2
35    2
71    1
```

From here, I'd like to create a new column in df, called count, which assigns freq=2 for each ID which corresponds to Location=54, for example. I.e., df would now look something like this:

```
df
ID  Location count 
 1   54      2
 2   35      2
 3   54      2
 4   35      2
 5   71      1
```

My real data contains too many Location values for me to feasibly write an ifelse statement to conditionally assign these count values. I'm not sure how to accomplish in an efficient manner (I could also create a null column and use the `replace` function in dplyr, but that would be similarly laborious. Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `add_count` from `dplyr` (in the devel version - soon to be released 0.6.0)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   add_count(Location)
# A tibble: 5 × 3
#     ID Location     n
#   <int>    <int> <int>
#1     1       54     2
#2     2       35     2
#3     3       54     2
#4     4       35     2
#5     5       71     1
```

---

But if we want to do this from the `table` output, we can use `merge`

```
merge(df, as.data.frame(table(df$Location)), by.x= "Location", by.y = "Var1")
```

Comment: oddly I get this error message: Error in function_list[[k]](value) : could not find function "add_count"

Comment: I believe that add_count is newly added to dplyr 0.6  and not in the main release yet. See https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/releases

Comment: @epi99 Yes, you are right, updated the post

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Location) %>%
  mutate(n = n())

#      ID Location     n
#   <int>    <int> <int>
# 1     1       54     2
# 2     2       35     2
# 3     3       54     2
# 4     4       35     2
# 5     5       71     1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ave` to count the `length` of the data corresponding to each `Location`

```
ave(1:NROW(df), df$Location, FUN = length)
#[1] 2 2 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to do this in `data.table` as well:

```
library(data.table)
dt[,count := .N, by = Location]

dt
#   ID Location count
#1:  1       54     2
#2:  2       35     2
#3:  3       54     2
#4:  4       35     2
#5:  5       71     1
```

**Data:**

```
dt <- fread("ID  Location  
              1   54
              2   35 
              3   54
              4   35
              5   71")
```